# OnEditable textbox of gridview not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, obout

I have took the code from [here](https://www.obout.com/grid/commands/aspnet_commands_excel_style_full.aspx) and implemented on my project, the issue is that it is working fine in IE. But not working on **CHROME**

Here is my code:-

```
<cc1:Grid ID="GrdConfirmation" EnableTypeValidation="true" runat="server" Width="100%"
    ShowFooter="false" AllowAddingRecords="true" AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    FolderStyle="../Styles/Grid/style_12">
    <ClientSideEvents OnClientSelect="GrdConfirmation_OnClientSelect" />
        <Columns>
        <cc1:Column ID="Column1" DataField="MKEY" HeaderText="Select" ReadOnly="true" Width="3%"
            runat="server">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="gtchkConfirm" HeaderTemplateId="HTConfirm" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Sr_No" DataField="Sr_No" HeaderText="Sr No" Visible="false" Width="0%">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="tplNumbering" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="col_save_srno" DataField="save_srno" HeaderText="Sr.No" Visible="true"
            Width="3%" Align="left">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Line_Id" DataField="Line_Id" HeaderText="Line id" Visible="false"
            Align="left" Width="0%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Item_Mkey" DataField="Item_Mkey" HeaderText="Item Mkey" Visible="false"
            Align="center" Width="0%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Item_Code" DataField="Item_Code" HeaderText="Item Code" Visible="true"
            Align="left" Width="5%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Item_Desc" DataField="Item_Desc" HeaderText="Item Description" Visible="true"
            Align="left" Width="13%" Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Lot_Batch_No" DataField="Lot_Batch_No" HeaderText="Lot / Batch No."
            Visible="true" Align="left" Width="7%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Exp_Dt" DataField="Exp_Dt" HeaderText="Exp Date" Visible="true" Align="left"
            Width="7%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="QTY1" DataField="Qty" HeaderText=" Quantity" Visible="true" Width="6%"
            Align="center">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Bx_Bg" DataField="Bx_Bg" HeaderText="Boxes/Bags" Visible="true" Width="6%"
            Align="center">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Net_Wgt" DataField="Net_Wgt" HeaderText="Net Weight" Visible="true" HeaderAlign="center"
            Width="6%" Align="center">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="NO_OF_PALLETS" DataField="NO_OF_PALLETS" HeaderText="No Of Pallets" HeaderAlign="center"
            Visible="true" Align="center" Width="5%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Default_Allot" DataField="Default_Allot" HeaderText="Allocated Storage Bin No."
            Visible="true" Width="10%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Confirmed_Allot" DataField="Confirmed_Allot" HeaderText="Confirmed Storage Bin No."
            Visible="true" Width="10%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Storage_type" DataField="Storage_type" HeaderText="Storage Type"
            Visible="false" Width="0%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Damaged_Qty" DataField="Damaged_Qty" HeaderText="Damaged Qty in Units"
            Visible="true" Width="5%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Short_Fall_Excess" DataField="Short_Fall_Excess" HeaderText="Shortfall/ excess qty in units"
            Visible="true" Width="5%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
    </Columns>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="PlainEditTemplate">
            <Template>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtconfirm" CssClass="excel-textbox" onfocus="markAsFocused(this)"
                    onblur="markAsBlured(this)" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <AddEditDeleteSettings AddLinksPosition="Bottom" NewRecordPosition="Dynamic" />
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="GridTemplate1">
            <Template>
                <input id="txttemp" type="text" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="HTConfirm">
            <Template>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleSelection(this)" id="ChkSelector" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="gtchkConfirm">
            <Template>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_grid" runat="server" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="TextBoxEditTemplate">
            <Template>
                <input type="text" name="TextBox1111" id="Txtconfirm<%# (Container.RecordIndex) %>"
                    class="excel-textbox" readonly="readonly" onfocus="GrdConfirmation.editWithTextBox(this)" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplNumbering">
            <Template>
                <b>
                    <%# (Container.RecordIndex + 1)%>
                </b>
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
        <cc1:GridTemplate ID="TemplateWithCheckbox">
            <Template>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkID" ToolTip="<%# Container.Value %>" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
</cc1:Grid>
```

Here is the related javascript function which I implemented

```
function toggleSelection(checkbox) {
        var con = confirm("Do you want check/unckeck all");
        if (con == true) {

            for (var ii = 0; ii < GrdConfirmation.getTotalNumberOfRecords(); ii++) {
                var idt = "GrdConfirmation_ob_GrdConfirmationBodyContainer_ctl34_" + ii + "_ctl00_" + ii + "_txtconfirm_" + ii;
                var idc = "GrdConfirmation_ob_GrdConfirmationBodyContainer_ctl02_" + ii + "_ctl00_" + ii + "_chk_grid_" + ii;

                if (document.getElementById(checkbox.id).checked == true) {
                    document.getElementById(idt).value = GrdConfirmation.Rows[ii].Cells[13].Value;
                    // alert(GrdConfirmation.Rows[ii].Cells[13].Value);
                    document.getElementById(idc).checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(idt).value = "";
                    document.getElementById(idc).checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried debugging my code in `Console` and below is the screenshot for the errors which was coming.

The error was

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image: Chrome console error screenshot]

Comment: What is not being found? Don't provide pictures of the errors please, paste the text, or include the full error in the picture.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: Actually there are no **errors** on the page, the only thing is that this functionality is not working in `chrome`

Comment: It is looking for resources which is not available either you should place the resources at the same place or remove where ever you are using this resource.

Comment: @शेखर: I didn't got you. what resource you are talking about.?

Comment: @शेखर: I resolved all those errors which wer coming in the console part, but still it is not working in chrome. There are no errors now.

Comment: try to count number of elements in the script part and use console to debug those.

Comment: @शेखर: `Number of elements` means ?

Comment: Here is a good example of debugging in chrome http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273129/Beginner-Guide-to-Page-and-Script-Debugging-with-C

Comment: @शेखर; I got the anwer ;) thanks a lot anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of research, I finally managed to get the answer,

I just added one property where I wanted to edit the textbox

```
AllowEdit="true"
```

Here is the full code:-

```
<cc1:Column ID="Confirmed_Allot" DataField="Confirmed_Allot" HeaderText="Confirmed Storage Bin No."
            Visible="true" Width="10%" Align="center" Wrap="true" AllowEdit="true" >
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
```